# Need help, why scroll event doesn't work using Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, scroll

I just installed to my Ember.js project ember-scrollable lib (https://github.com/alphasights/ember-scrollable) using npm:
npm i ember-scrollable@0.3.5 --save
and included my code into {{#ember-scrollable tag.

I used this lib according official manual (https://github.com/alphasights/ember-scrollable), and on the first side I did everything correct. Maybe somebody knows, what I did incorrect. The main idea is that to get event when i scroll to the bottom of the table. Also no matter what the npm-lib will use to reach this, but I need to get example of workable solution on git or other source, because I didn't find it on the internet.

```
{{#ember-scrollable
    onScrolledToBottom=(action 'log' 'Bottom reached!')
}}
    ...TABLE CONTENT
{{/ember-scrollable}}
```

In my case, when i opened console, I got an error:

> ember.debug.js:2532 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined at DOMHelper.prototype.setAttribute (ember.debug.js:2532)

Comment: You reported your issue 16 hours ago on GitHub repository of that library: https://github.com/alphasights/ember-scrollable/issues/116 Maybe you should wait a little bit for a response there?

Comment: There doesn't close the issue for at least two years.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you want to fire the event [ember-in-viewport](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-in-viewport) which you would add to a component at the end of the table to fire an event when it is shown or [ember-light-table](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-light-table) which has infinite scrolling built in may be a good place to investigate for a solution (or use out of the box if they fit your use case).